# Changing Rails 2 Routes to Rails 3 Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm trying to change my routes from a rails 2 project to match the syntax in rails 3. How would I change this:

```
    map.connect "/stylesheets/:action.css", 
            :controller => "stylesheets", 
            :format => "css"
```

so that the `:action` can be matched to an action from the stylesheets controller?
Would it be something like this?

`match 'stylesheets/:action.css', :to => "stylesheets#{:action}"`

Also, what is the syntax for `:format` in the routes for rails 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there with your solution. The only thing you have to change is the way you reference `:action` in the `:to` value.

```
match 'stylesheets/:action.css', :to => 'stylesheets#:action', :format => :css
```

As you can see, the syntax for `:format` didn't change.

Comment: does it matter if i have a `/` in front of stylesheets in `match 'stylesheets/:action.css'` or not? like `match '/stylesheets/:action.css'`

Comment: As far as I know it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be smth like:

```
match 'stylesheets/:action', :controller => :stylesheets, :defaults => { :format => :css }
```

or you can constraint your routes to **.css** format using `:constraints => { :format => 'json' }`

I recommend you to read through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: so I wouldn't need a `:to =>` ?

Comment: @Edmund you need to specify controller in this case, take a look at the code.